# Python how to elegantly handle the usage of different data structures?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm using Python 3.5 and this is the code I'm dealing with at the moment:

```
def is_odd_number(n):
    """states if n is an odd number"""
    return n % 2 == 1


def collatz_next(n):
    """returns the successor to n in Collatz sequence"""
    return 3*n + 1 if is_odd_number(n) else n//2


def collatz_seq_sum(seq):
    """returns the sum of all elements to a given Collatz sequence"""
    return sum(seq)


def collatz_seq(n):
    """returns the Collatz sequence to n"""
    l = []
    l.append(n)
    current = n
    while current != 1:
        next_one = collatz_next(current)
        l.append(next_one)
        current = next_one
    return l


def collatz_seqs(lower_limit=1, upper_limit=10):
    """returns Collatz sequences from lower_limit to upper_limit"""
    return {i: collatz_seq(i) for i in range(lower_limit, upper_limit+1)}
```

I think that type `list` is best when dealing with a single Collatz sequence. That's why `collatz_seq` returns a list. However, I find it interesting to observe how this particular sequence develops when dealing with multiple parameters `n` in a row. That's why I created `collatz_seqs`.

I do not like `collatz_seq_sum` for a very simple reason: it only works properly if its parameter `seq` is of type `list`. In my opinion it's not the responsibility of `collatz_seq_sum` to make sure that a proper actual parameter is provided, in this case a `list` comprised of natural numbers. In my opinion the caller to `collatz_seq_sum` has to make sure that it's provided a correct parameter.

I want `collatz_sum_seq` to work with single and multiple sequences. `collatz_seq` returns a `list` and `collatz_seqs` returns a `dict`. Therefore my question: what's the elegant way to make sure that `collatz_seq_sum` always gets the correct data type for its parameter `seq`? What can I do for `collatz_seq_sum` to properly work without `collatz_seq_sum` caring about the data type of its parameter `seq`? My first idea was to change `collatz_seq` to have it return a `dict` instead of a `list` and changing `collatz_seq_sum` in order to process a `dict`. However, I don't like this approach because I don't want a `dict` when dealing with a single sequence.

Do you have any solutions to that? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) static type checking library provides a [decorator](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/11/29/improve-your-python-decorators-explained/) named `overload` that seems to allow the kind of polymorphism you want: http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/function_overloading.html . Looks promising to me.

Comment: Would [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to do polymorphism for functions in python is to check the type of the argument given:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping, Iterable

def collatz_seq_sum(seq):
    """returns the sum of all elements to a given Collatz sequence"""
    if isinstance(seq, Mapping):
        ret = {key: sum(values) for key, values in seq.items()}
    elif isinstance(seq, Iterable):
        ret = sum(seq)
    else:
        msg = "collatz_seq_sum got unexpected type: '{}'".format(type(seq))
        raise TypeError(msg)
    return ret
```

if you want a function to behave differently depending on the type of the input this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's a fine argument and I understand it. I was just wondering: is this the only approach? Say you use scripts which utilize hundreds if not thousands of functions. I mean it's always the same thing over and over again: each function checks for the type of its parameters and acts accordingly. To do the same thing over and over again gets incredibly tedious and I think it's difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: that is what classes (and duck-typing) is for. this is the python philosophy of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want `collatz_seq_sum` to work with both a dict of collatz sequences or an individual collatz sequence. In the case of a dictionary, you want the function to return a dictionary of the sums of individual collatz sequences.

You can use `isinstance` to check whether the input `seq` is a dictionary or a list and run different code for each case. The following code would work.

```
def collatz_seq_sum(seq):
    """returns the sum of all elements to a given Collatz sequence"""
    if isinstance(seq, dict):
        return {i: sum(seqi) for i, seqi in seq.items()}
    else:
        return sum(seq)
```

However, if you what you want is sum of all sequences of the dict, you could use the following instead,

```
def collatz_seq_sum(seq):
    """returns the sum of all elements to a given Collatz sequence"""
    if isinstance(seq, dict):
        return sum([sum(seqi) for i, seqi in seq.items()])
    else:
        return sum(seq)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Well, not exactly. I do not want `collatz_seq_sum` to bother with the data type of `seq` at all because I don't think that it's the job of `collatz_seq_sum` to check for data types. It's its job to calculate sums; nothing else.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want collatz_seq_sum to work on any data type, without checking for the data type?

Comment: Yes, that's the basic idea because I don't want to make pretty much the same check when dealing with hundreds of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.4+ - [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) lets you *overload* a function definition based on the argument's type.

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def collatz_seq_sum(seq):
    '''returns the sum of all elements to a given Collatz sequence'''
    raise NotImplementedError("I can't handle that data type")

@collatz_seq_sum.register(list)
def _(seq):
    return sum(seq)

@collatz_seq_sum.register(dict)
def _(seq):
    return {key: sum(values) for key, values in seq.items()}

>>> collatz_seq_sum([1,2,3,4,5])
15
>>> collatz_seq_sum({'a': [1,1,1,1], 'b': [2,2,2,2]})
{'a': 4, 'b': 8}
```

Calling `collatz_seq_sum` with something other than list or dict will raise a `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is a very interesting approach as well. You used the word "overload". Is your code an application of Python's decorator functionality? The @-sign reminds me of it.

Comment: @6q9nqBjo,  I took the word overload from it's documentation. It is a decorator - I haven't taken the time to look and see how it is implemented.  There is a link to the docs in my answer.